# tp4056 circuit to charge 18650 1s battery

Tags: batteries, tp4056

I am making a single 18560 battery charger pcb module like tp4056 module (because it is not available in my country), after some researches my schematic is here, but actually i am not sure about it, is it right?

[image]

the circuit contains tp4056 ic to charge the battery connect to a double mosfet (fs8205) and dw01 to protect the battery from overvoltage and current.

Comment: Welcome! _”not available in my country”_ Most retailers ship all over the world. Besides, your schematic uses the IC anyway so you can buy it? What does each output on the right connect to?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your schematic are

- You have selected a charging current of 1 A for the battery charger section (1k2 resistor connected to PROG pin).
- You have selected 25-mR dual MOSFETs so that the DW01 triggers over-current protection at 3 A and above (ref voltage is 150 mV, total on-state resistance is 50 mOhms, so the OCP should trigger at 3 A).

If these are your design goals then the schematic looks correct in principal.

Couple of things my eyes have caught:

- TP4056 typical application circuit suggests an input bypass capacitor of 10 uF but yours has 100 nF.
- Apparently the charger and the protection circuit will be on the same board. So,

  1. When the charger is on (input from the USB is applied) the battery's load should be disconnected. Or else the charger may try to supply the load. This may cause some charging problems.
  2. What happens when there's a situation like charger's input disconnected whilst the battery connected is not clear. TP4056 may or may not get damaged. Who knows if it's happy with an external voltage applied to its BAT pin whilst there's no input voltage at its VCC pin... I don't.

Comment: most circuit use 100nf capacitor!!,
-  the load will be connected with on/off switch so can not so won't work while charging
- for the point number two how to avoid this scenario